# 2 foreign keys referencing same table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

Can I have two foreign keys in the same table that are referencing an other table named profil(same one) ?

my table is MailSent, it contains : primary key (Id), date, foreignkey1 (profil_sender), foreignkey2 (profil_receiver)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add foreign keys `(profil_sender_id, profil_receiver_id)` to an existing table `(MailSent)`, follow the following steps:

```
ALTER TABLE MailSent ADD CONSTRAINT fk_profile_sender_id FOREIGN KEY (profil_sender_id) REFERENCES TABLE-NAME(id);

ALTER TABLE MailSent ADD CONSTRAINT fk_profil_receiver_id FOREIGN KEY (profil_receiver_id) REFERENCES TABLE-NAME(id);
```

Comment: So it is correct, I thought I should have only one foreign key "profil_id" and then I can get all the other fields using the id

Comment: If you add foreign key `profile_id` in your table you get all information about foreign key reference table`(e.g. profile)` using `profile_id`.

Comment: Yes. It's correct. More about foreign key go to the link: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Comment: is there a way i can guarantee (profil_sender_id, profil_receiver_id) are never the same ? 
or is my responsability at all times on input ?

Answer (score 13):

We can have tow foreign keys referencing the same table, and as mentioned in '@zhou yun' answer to achieve this the table will be like this:

```
create table MailSent(

  Id int primary key,

  profil_sender_id int,

  profil_receiver_id int,

  FOREIGN KEY (profil_sender_id) REFERENCES profil(id),

  FOREIGN KEY (profil_receiver_id) REFERENCES profil(id)

)
```

and to select from this two table and join the two table using the both foreign key the request will be like that :

```
SELECT ms.*, ps.first_name as name_sender,pr.first_name as name_reciver  
FROM MailSent ms 
LEFT JOIN profil ps 
ON ms.profil_sender_id= ps.id
LEFT JOIN profil pr 
ON ms.profil_receiver_id= pr.id
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add foreign keys when create the table, could do like this:

```
create table MailSent(

  Id int primary key,

  date datetime,

  profil_sender int,

  profil_receiver int,

  CONSTRAINT fk_sender FOREIGN KEY (profil_sender) REFERENCES profil(id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_receiver FOREIGN KEY (profil_receiver) REFERENCES profil(id)

)
```